# SOCKet Secure (SOCKS) server for Android

Tags: android, proxy, socks

I am looking for SOCKS servers recommendation which can be run on Android handset. I already did google search and stackoverflow search but could not find a SOCKS version 4 or 5 server implementation that can be run on Android.

FYI: I already tried "Tetherbot" but its as the site says it not production quality. Hence looking for more option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using JSOCKS (http://jsocks.sourceforge.net/)

It worked great for us. This way be useful for someone else.

Comment: I have added its jar file to my build path but how to use it to connect with socks server?